# Mean Absolute Deviation in m.v. portfolio optimization

Tags: portfolio-optimization, mean-variance, risk-models

I just read some articles about $MAD$ as a measure of risk in finance.

Is the following formulation a correct way to implement a $MAD$ portfolio optimization model which minimizes risk without considering expected return?

Assuming returns to be Gaussian distributed one can use $MAD=E(|X|)=\sigma \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}$. The problem then can be written:

$$ w^* = {{\underset{w}{\mathrm{arg\ min}}}  = \sqrt{w^T\Sigma w}\cdot \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}}\\ s.t.,\  1^Tw=1 $$

Once the assumption of Gaussian distributed returns is removed how the model can be formulated using matrix notation?

Comment: There is quite a bit of literature on MAD portfolio optimization, which I don't know very well. There is a somewhat famous paper in this area: Konno, H., & Yamazaki, H. (1991). Mean-absolute deviation portfolio optimization model and its applications to Tokyo stock market. Management Science, 37(5), 519-531. And here is a comparison beween Markowitsz and MAD https://scholar.rose-hulman.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1262&context=rhumj

Comment: Thank-you for the suggestion. Unfortunately I have not found a free access to the paper. In any case all the articles I considered provide formulations of the MAD model that require returns estimation (which is not the case for the above one)

Comment: This is not the full paper.

Comment: Sorry, my fault.

Comment: @noob2 no problem ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can handle this problem with scenario
optimization: assume a matrix $R$ of returns, in which
the rows are the scenarios and the columns are
assets. For given portfolio weights $w$, you can
compute the portfolio returns as $Rw$.  You can now
evaluate an objective function such as the MAD, so your objective becomes $\min\ \mathrm{mean}(|Rw|)$. Now feed this model to an appropriate solver.

The paper mentioned by @noob2,

```
@ARTICLE{Konno1991,
  author       = {Konno, Hiroshi and Yamazaki, Hiroaki},
  title        = {Mean-Absolute Deviation Portfolio Optimization Model
                  and Its Applications to {T}okyo Stock Market},
  journal      = {Management Science},
  year         = 1991,
  volume       = 37,
  pages        = {519--531},
  number       = 5,
}
```

describes how to solve this model via linear programming.